# Why does UICollectionView conform to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout by default?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, protocols, uicollectionviewdelegate

I'm just confused with the following code that gets executed in a `UICollectionViewController` instantiated from a xib file:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1.0;
}
```

which is declared in the protocol `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. However, there is nowhere in the `UICollectionViewController` showing that it would conform to this protocol, as declared in the `UICollectionViewController`:

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) @interface UICollectionViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
```

Can anyway explain why `UICollectionViewController` would conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the class of a collection view's layout when dragged into a xib/storyboard is `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, which is why by default the delegate methods for `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` are called. If you were to change the layout object's class in the xib/storyboard, none of the methods specific to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` would be called.

Also, `UICollectionViewController` may privately conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, or it may not. It doesn't really matter because a class doesn't *technically* have to explicitly conform to a protocol in order to implement and respond to methods in that protocol.